# Author not included when submitting an answer

Tags: bug

I just tried to submit an answer to a question on Stack Overflow, but when submitting, an error occurred:

> Your answer couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above.

There was no error "above" (see exact screenshot the bottom)

However, the console revealed an error. The following request was sent:

**POST stackoverflow.com/questions/40728554/answer/submit**

and the response was:

```
    {
        "success": false,
        "errors": {
            "Email": [
                "An email is required to post."
            ]
        },
        "warnings": {},
        "source": {}
    }
```

**I was indeed logged in** when submitting the answer. Still, the query parameter didn't seem to include me as an author:

[image: Query parameter "author"]

To me, this seems like a bug, but why it occurred for this specific case, I do not know. I have successfully submitted answers before. The error occurred several times in the same session, also after a reload and a draft discard. I have not tried other browsers or similar, as I do not want to lose potential error data.

[image: Submit screenshot]

Comment: Looks definitely like a bug, though you should again think about if you really should be submitting this answer. If clearing the cache is really the solution, it's questionable if the question shouldn't be closed.

Comment: Yes, maybe it's just your email isn't detected, try with secret mode or with anothe browser and you will see if it's your account or a SO bug

Comment: Can confirm that this bug is still happening.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me. A hard refresh of the page worked.